# $R$ is a ring. $(R,+)\cong(Z_2\oplus Z_4,+)$, indecomposable, $\nexists$ 1, noncommutative, has an idempotent $e\neq 0$. Show that $2e\neq 0$.

Tags: ring-theory, finite-rings

Let $R$ be an indecomposable ring with $(R,+)\cong(\Bbb{Z}_2\oplus \Bbb{Z}_4,+)$.
Suppose that $R$ is noncommutative and has no multiplicative identity.
If $R$ has an nonzero idempotent element $e$, show that $2e\neq 0$.

---

The original question come from the paper
"Rings of order $p^3$",
writed by V. G. Antipkin and V. P. Elizarov.
Which paper classify the rings of order $p^3$.
http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF00968650

The author separate the problem into many cases,
one of the cases is

- $R$ is indecompoable
- $(R,+)\cong (\Bbb{Z}_p\oplus \Bbb{Z}_{p^2},+)$
- $R$ is noncommutative
- $R$ has no unity
- $R$ has a nonzero idempotent element $e$

The author prove that the additive order of $e$ is $p^2$ by contradiction.
He suppose that the additive order of $e$ is $p$.
There are three cases, $Re=R$, $|Re|=p^2$ and $|Re|=p$.
My question occur in the case $|Re|=p^2$.
The author says that:

If $|Re|=p^2$, then $char Re=char R(1-e)=p$
and we find again that $char R=p$,
a contradiction.
(Because $char R=p^2$.)

I doubt the statement $char Re=char R(1-e)$ is wrong.
I find out a counterexample when $p=2$.
Since $(R,+)\cong (\Bbb{Z}_2\oplus \Bbb{Z}_4,+)$, 
suppose that $(R,+)\cong \langle b\rangle +\langle e\rangle$,
where $e$ is the idempotent
and the additive order of $e$ is $2$ and the additive order of $b$ is 4.
Then $R=\{0,b,2b,3b,e,b+e,2b+e,3b+e\}$, 
$Re=\{0,be,e,be+e\}$, 
$R(1-e)=R-Re=\{0,2b,3b-be,b-be\}$.
$$
2=char Re\neq char R(1-e)=4.
$$

The complete table of the rings of order 8
http://bfhaha.blogspot.tw/p/rings-of-order-8.html

Comment: This is an interesting flavored question. Where is it from?

Comment: How do you define "idempotent": $e^2=e$ or $e^n=e$ for some $n$?

Comment: @AlexM. $e^2=e$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lemma 1:
Suppose $R$ is a ring.
If $A$ and $B$ are two ideals of $R$ and
$R=A+B, A\cap B=\{0\}$,
then $R\cong A\oplus B$.
See the Hungerford's book: Algebra, p.130, theorem 2.24.

Lemma 2:
Let $R$ be a ring
not necessary has a multiplicative identity.
Suppose that $e$ is a nonzero idempotent element
and for all $r\in R$, $re=er$.
That is, $e\in Z(R)$, the center of the ring $R$.
Let $A=eR=\{ er\mid r\in R\}$,
$B=\{r-er\mid r\in R\}$.
Then $A$ and $B$ are two ideals of $R$ and $R\cong A\oplus B$.

Lemma 3:
Let $R$ be a ring
not necessary has a multiplicative identity.
If $e$ is an idempotent element in $R$
and $eR=Re$,
then $e\in Z(R)$.
See T. Y. Lam's book: Exercises in classical ring theory 2e,
p.316, exercise 22.3 A.

The proof of these lemma see the end of this answer.

---

We state the theorem again,
the hypothesis noncommutative, $\nexists$, has no unity are redundant.

Let $R$ be an indecomposable ring
with $(R,+)\cong(\Bbb{Z}_2\oplus \Bbb{Z}_4,+)$.
If $R$ has a nonzero idempotent element $e$,
then $ord(e)=4$,
where $ord(x)$ denote the additive order 
of the element $x$.

The proof of the theorem.

Since $|(R,+)|=4$,
by Lagrange's Theorem,
$ord(e)\in\{1, 2, 4\}$.
Since $e\neq 0$,
so $ord(e)\neq 1$.
If $ord(e)=2$,
then we select $b\in R$,
where $ord(b)=4$,
suct that
$R=\langle e\rangle +\langle b\rangle=\{0,b,2b,3b,e,b+e,2b+e,3b+e\}$.
It is easy to know that $Re=\{0,be,e,be+e\}$
and $eR=\{0,eb,e,eb+e\}$.
There are three cases,
$|Re|=4$, $|eR|=4$ and $|Re|=|eR|=2$.
We show that whatever which case,
there is a contradiction.
Therefore, $ord(e)=4$.

If $|Re|=4$,
then $be\neq e$ and $be\neq 0$.
Since $2(be)=b(2e)=0$
and there are three elements $2b, e$ and $2b+e$ in $R$
whose additive order is 2.
Thus, $be\in \{2b, 2b+e\}$.
If $be=2b$,
then $be=be^2=(be)e=2be=b(2e)=0$,
a contradiction.
Similarly,
$be=2b+e$ implies that $be=be^2=(be)e=(2b+e)e=2be+e^2=e$,
a contradiction.
Therefore, $|Re|\neq 4$.
By the similar argument,
we have $|eR|\neq 4$.

The remain case is $|eR|=|Re|=2$.
In this case,
since $\{0,e\}\subseteq Re,eR$,
hence $Re=eR$.
By Lemma 3,
$e\in Z(R)$.
Furthermore,
by Lemma 2,
$R\cong eR\oplus (R-eR)$.
Since $eR\neq R$,
contrary to the hypothesis $R$ is indecomposable.

---

The proof of Lemma 2:
$A$ and $B$ are ideals of $R$ could be directly verified,
we only verify some axioms of the ideal.
$$
\forall er_1, er_2\in eR, (er_1)(er_2)
\stackrel{e\in Z(R)}{=}
e^2 r_1 r_2
\stackrel{e^2=e}{=}
e r_1 r_2\in eR,
$$
$$
\forall er\in eR, r'\in R, r'er
\stackrel{e\in Z(R)}{=}
err'\in eR.
$$
For all $r\in R$, $r=er+(r-er)\in A+B$, then $R=A+B$.
If $x=er_1=r_2-er_2\in A\cap B$,
then multiplying $e$
to both side of this identity,
we get $$ ex=e^2r_1=er_2-e^2 r_2=er_2-er_2=0. $$
Then $$ x=er_1=e^2 r_1=e(er_1)=ex=0. $$
That is, $A\cap B=\{0\}$.
Then by Lemma 1,
$R\cong A\oplus B$.

The proof of Lemma 3:
For all $r\in R$.
\begin{eqnarray*}
& & er-ere=e(r-re)\in eR=Re\\
& \Rightarrow & er-ere=r_1 e...(*)\\
& \stackrel{\mbox{right multiplying }e}{\Rightarrow} & ere-ere^2=r_1 e^2=r_1 e\\
& \Rightarrow & r_1 e=0\\
& \stackrel{(*)}{\Rightarrow} & er-ere=r_1 e=0\\
& \Rightarrow & er=ere.
\end{eqnarray*}

Similarly, since $re-ere=(r-er)e\in Re=eR$,
we can get $re=ere$.
Therefore, $er=ere=re$.